# Pregunta acerca de la declaracion de strings como tipos de dato en funciones

Tags: c++, funciones

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Cliente.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream creditoSalida("credito.dat", ios:: binary);

if(!creditoSalida){
    cerr << " No se pudo abrir el archivo. " << endl;
    exit(1);
}

Cliente clienteEnBlanco;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)

    creditoSalida.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *> (&clienteEnBlanco), sizeof(Cliente));
return 0;
}
```

clientes.h

```
#ifndef CLIENTE_H
#define CLIENTE_H

class Cliente
{
  private:

  int numeroCuenta;

  char apellido[15];

  char primerNombre[10];

  string prueba = "";

  double saldo;

  public:
     Cliente(int = 0, string = "", string = "", double = 0.0);

    void establecerNumeroCuenta(int);
    int obtenerNumeroCuenta();
    void establecerApellido(string);
    string obtenerApellido();
    void establecerPrimerNombre(string);
    string obtenerPrimerNombre();
    void establecerSaldo(double);
    double obtenerSaldo();
};

#endif // CLIENTE_H
```

cliente.cpp

```
#include "Cliente.h"

Cliente::Cliente(int valorNumeroCuenta, string valorApellido, string   valorPrimerNombre, double valorSaldo)
{
   establecerNumeroCuenta(valorNumeroCuenta);
establecerApellido(valorApellido);
establecerPrimerNombre(valorPrimerNombre);
establecerSaldo(valorSaldo);
}

void Cliente::establecerNumeroCuenta(int valorNumeroCuenta)
{
     numeroCuenta = valorNumeroCuenta;
}

int Cliente::obtenerNumeroCuenta()
{
    return numeroCuenta;
}

void Cliente::establecerApellido(string valorApellido)
{
     apellido = valorApellido;
}

string Cliente::obtenerApellido()
{
    return apellido;
}

void Cliente::establecerPrimerNombre(string valorPrimerNombre)
{

    primerNombre = valorPrimerNombre;
}

string Cliente::obtenerPrimerNombre()
{
   return primerNombre;
}

void Cliente::establecerSaldo(double valorSaldo)
{
   saldo = valorSaldo;
}

double Cliente::obtenerSaldo()
{
  return saldo;
}
```

A la hora de compilar me sale un error que dice que: "Error : string does not name a type " este error señala a una de los prototipo de funciones que tengo como         "string obtenerApellido();" ¿Por qué ? parace ser que no reconoce a string como un tipo de dato para un prototipo de función, pero los demás tipos de dato si los acepta como funciones

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta rápida (mañana la desarrollo):

Te ha faltado incluir la librería string, con la línea:

```
#include <string>
```

Esta librería es parte de las librerías estándar de c++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Los otros tipos de datos (void, int, char, etc.) Son tipos básicos del sistema, por lo que no hace falta definirlos ni incluir ninguna librería que los defina.

Comment: No funciono pero gracias